# Incomplete pointer used in child class - Error: use of undefined type

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, protected, circular-dependency

Okay... I have understood this question about circular dependency and forward declaration, but I am having trouble understanding a particular error that involve inheritance and pointer-based variables.

I will show snippets of the relevant code:

Player is the derived class from Entity

Entity.hpp

```
class Entity : public sf::Sprite{

private:

    int health;
    float speed;
    sf::Time spawntime;
    bool invincible;


protected:

    SceneGame *myScene; // let's keep it at null
                        // since setScene will take care of it

   public:

// more code....

void setScene(SceneGame *scene){myScene = scene;};
    SceneGame* getScene(){return myScene;};

};
```

player.cpp // Assume player.h is complete

myScene is accessible to any classes derived form Entity

```
void Player::shootPlayer(float dt){

    // we reduce time for shoot delay

    shootDelay -= dt;

    if (shootDelay < 0.0f) return;

    resetDelay();

    if (Input::instance()->pressKeybutton(sf::Keyboard::Space)){



        // I know I set SceneGame* myScene as protected back in Entity class.
        // However, because it is claimed to be undefined,
        // despite being forward-declared back in entity,
        // I'm getting the 'use of undefined type class' error C2027

        sf::Texture bulletTex;
        bulletTex = (myScene->game->texmgr.getRef("bulletPlayer"));


        Bullet* bullet_p = new Bullet(bulletTex,
            1, 10, false, false, 0.0f);

        bullet_p->setPosition(this->getGlobalBounds().width,
                              this->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);

    }
}
```

link to answered question:
[Forward declaration & circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802485/forward-declaration-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a forward declaration of `SceneGame`, likely in `entity.hpp` in the form of `class SceneGame;`. This is enough to use it as a pointer.

In `player.cpp`, you actually use the class and you need to know its details ( that you don't need in the header). Likely, your `player.cpp` should include a `SceneGame.hpp` (or wherever your `SceneGame` class is actually defined)

Fix by adding `#include "SceneGame.hpp"` at the end of the includes in your `player.cpp`file.

Comment: Thanks... I realized I do not need to do forward declaration in the player file. I only need the include.

Forward declarations are only useful when I have to represent a variable of a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have forward declared the `SceneGame` class, you *have* to include the full definition before you start using any methods of that class, otherwise, how does the compiler know which methods the `SceneGame` class supports?

I'd expect that you need to `#include "SceneGame.h"` or similar in your Player.cpp file.