# Circular dependency with Dependency walker due to forwarded functions?

Tags: circular-dependency, dependency-walker

When checking a dll, [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) reports `Error: A circular dependency was detected.`

The [documentation says](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/overview_2.htm)

> Detects circular dependency errors. This is a very rare error, but can occur with forwarded functions.

What does *forwarded function* mean in this context?

PS: The alternative [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) doesn't seem to give an error output.

Comment: [I guess that would relate to type 3 here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/dependency_types.htm). And maybe type 4. [Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802485/forward-declaration-circular-dependency).

Comment: Circular Dependency: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-circular-dependencies-How-do-I-avoid-them). And we need to turn to Raymond Chen again: [Exported functions that are really forwarders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473).